# How to pass an "int" value into any bits of a "char" array?

Tags: c

```
int x = 10;
char denemem[13]="|          |";
```

How can I get the output shown below by writing a code in C programming language? or, more precisely, how can I pass **int** into the any place
(any bits) of a **char** array I want?

```
|    10    |
```

Thank you for all of your help and efforts in advance!

Comment: You described what you want, not what have you tried.

Comment: You should make `denemem` a format string for `printf()`.

Comment: What output do you want when `x` is 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, etc? I note that your desired output for `10` has 12 characters; you can't create a string with 12 characters in `denemem` — it doesn't have enough room for a terminal null byte which is crucial to C strings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a fixed width, printf can do that directly, as long as you want left or right justified:

```
printf("|%10d|", x);    // right justified
printf("|%-10d|", x);   // left justified
```

Unfortunately, if you want the number centered in a field, that is much harder to do.  You need to figure out how wide the number is and then pad:

```
int width = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", x);
if (width <= 10) {
    width += (10-width)/2;
    printf("|%*d%*s|", width, x, 10-width, "");
} else {
    // number is too wide for the field -- do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below, I hope you will understand from my comments that there is an easy way to pass a string or integer to any bit of your array you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    
    int x = 10; 
    // this is our integer value and we want to pass it to denemem[13]
    
    char denemem[13]="|          |";   
    // denemem[13] I make 13 instead of 12 on purpose, 
    // because we want to print the number right in the center 
    // and at the end of every string in C language there is 1 character "\0", namely, "terminating character"
    // So, we have got 14 characters now
    
    //now, we need to convert the integer value in "x" to string first to pass it to our own string later on
    char mystr[50];
    sprintf(mystr, "%d", x);
    // get the value in "x" in decimal and then save it in "mystr"
    // by doing this, we converted the integer value in "x" to string in "mystr"
    // and now, we can pass it to any bits of our "denemem" array we want
    
    denemem[5] = mystr[0];             
    // writing the first bit (bit 0) of mystr into the fifth bit (bit 5) of denemem
    
    denemem[6] = mystr[1];            
    // writing the second bit (bit 1) of mystr into the sixth bit (bit 6) of denemem
    
    printf("%s", denemem);           
    // print what's in denemem

    return 0;
}
```